# vba code to know each person who modified an excel file

Tags: excel, vba6

we have a file modified by me and some colleagues our purpose is to show the changes done to this file by every person ( who added sheets in this file, those who used functions, who deleted sheets,....) using a vba code

i used the following vba code but it did not run in fact  the code need to be created before changes , code from extendoffice https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3961-excel-track-changes-without-sharing-workbook.html#a1 :

```vb
    Option Explicit
    Dim mStrRgAddress As String
    Dim mStrRgValue As String

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Const xRg As String = "A1:Z1000"
Const xSheetName As String = "Record sheet" 'The sheet that you want to put the track changes, please change the sheet name to your own.
Dim strOld As String
Dim strNew As String
Dim strCmt As String
Dim xLen As Long
Dim xSheet As Worksheet
Dim xRgCell As Range
Dim xRgCell2 As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set xSheet = Application.Sheets.Item(xSheetName)
If mStrRgAddress <> "" Then
Set xRgCell = Range(mStrRgAddress)
If xRgCell.Text <> mStrRgValue Then
strCmt = mStrRgAddress & " : " & Format$(Now, "dd Mmm YYYY hh:nn:ss") & " by " & _
Application.UserName & Chr(10) & "Previous Text :- " & mStrRgValue
Set xRgCell2 = xSheet.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp)
If xRgCell2.AddressLocal = xSheet.Range("A1").AddressLocal Then
If xRgCell2.Value <> "" Then
Set xRgCell2 = xRgCell2.Offset(1, 0)
End If
Else
Set xRgCell2 = xRgCell2.Offset(1, 0)
End If
xRgCell2.Value = strCmt
End If
End If
If xSheet.Name = Sh.Name Then Exit Sub
mStrRgValue = Target.Text
mStrRgAddress = Target.AddressLocal(False, False, , True)
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot in advance for any response